# Show content if not current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have conversations setup for the inbox messaging system. In the messages view there could be several messages viewed inside one message that is between two users. What I would like is in the view is to show which message is from which of the two users since this is a conversation.

The code I am using now shows the `message.sender` for all the messages. I need it to show the `message.sender` only for the messages where they're the sender only (not the recipient) of the message.

_message.html.erb:

```
<div class="message">
  <div class="created_at"><%= message.created_at.present? ? message.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") : message.created_at %></div><b>From: <%= @message.sender %></b>
  <div class="content">
    <%=h message.body %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you got it backwards (show the sender when its not them). I'd recommend checking in the controller the condition like

```
@is_sender = @message.sender.id == @user.id
```

or something like that. Beware of how you're using the @message variable. In your example you are using with and without @ (instance variables, the ones with @, are the ones you can create in your controller and access in the view as well).

GL & HF.